# Sanitizing raw_input?

Tags: python, security, sanitization, raw-input

I'm working on a chat tool where I need to have user manually input an ECDHE public key (64 hex chars). I'll summarize why it's needed just by saying it's got to do with hardware isolation. The issue is, there is a slight possibility user follows malicious instructions and enters an arbitrary string to the software. I'm worried that the input might exploit python interpreter or my code.

To prevent the latter, I'm validating character input by iterating through the string and checking whether the char is on allowed list of hex chars. I then compare then length with `==`. After that, key is converted to binary using `binascii.unhexlify()`.

Is there something else that I should be doing to secure the input, or that I should be taking into account? What's the safest and earliest possible way to detect string has incorrect format?

I'll add a graceful exit to `MemoryException` in case system runs out of memory. I would assume the dynamic memory allocation won't encounter serious problems but I'm still worried; Has the function had vulnerabilities in the past?

Also, I understand `eval()` with **python3** and input with **python2** are completely unsafe. I'm going to be porting my **python2** code into 3 some time in the future. How can I ensure **python3** code with it's `input()` isn't handled like `eval(raw_input())` if it's executed using **python2** interpreter?

Comment: Make sure to use a careful whitefish to all inputs, and check for buffer overflows. You should try to avoid letting any user input be evaled if possible. If you must, the best thing you can do is whitelist.

Comment: Whitelisting isn't possible since input space is 2^256. There's not enough particles on this planet to use as memory to store all valid inputs.

Comment: You don't store the full valid inputs. Whitefish the valid characters. So if you only want alphanumeric characters, than just check if each character in the input string is one of the white listed characters. If they all are, it is valid. Note that depending on your valid characters, there may be room for some code injection. In that case you would also want to use an additional blacklist.